# Write Django QuerySet that remove all whitespace from specific Keys within a JSONFIELD

Tags: django, django-queryset

I would like to write a Django QuerySet that removes whitespaces from Specific Keys within a JsonField.

I have a django model with a JsonField type.

```
MyModel(Model):
     a: str,
     properties: JSONField
```

this is an example of database lines :

```
a, properties

“first”, {“key_1”: “  key1value”, “key_2”:”key2value”, “key_3”: “  key_3”}
“second”, {“key_2”: “    key2   “}
```

and my queryset should update my data removing whitespace of specific key. So for Key_1 and Key_2 it will give me:

```
“first”, {“key_1”: “key1value”, “key_2”:”key2value”, “key_3”: “  key_3”}
    “second”, {“key_2”: “key2“}
```

I tried using

```
MyModel.objects.update(properties_key_1=F("propertieskey_1”).strip().lower(), propertieskey_2=F("properties_key_2”).strip().lower())
```

but I get an error:

==> result  AttributeError: 'F' object has no attribute 'strip

I tried:

```
MyModel.objects.update(properties__key_1=RawSQL("properties->key_1->value", []).strip()) ==> result 'RawSQL' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

I tried:

```
MyModel.objects.update(properties__key_1=RawSQL("TRIM(properties->asset_class->value)”)
==>      SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Any idea please ?
thx you

Comment: why are you using F() object instead of calling the value by key and just using a string object

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: instead of F("propertieskey_1”).strip().lower() just use dict.get(key).strip().lower()

Comment: i’ve already tried it  MyModel.objects.update(properties__key_1 = properties.get(‘key’_1).strip().lower())  i got NameError: name 'properties' is not defined

i have to use a loop and go over the models for using ‘dict.get(key).strip().lower() ‘